# iOS - Loading an image from a web server in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, image, ipad

At the moment, I have a goal of writing an application that contains a UIImageView. Upon loading or pressing a button, an image from a web server will load into the view.

What is the simplest way to do this? I'm assuming using the API described here? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

In the mean time, I will continue to try to get this working on my own. Any advice would be appreciated, especially if you have written code like this before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this can be done by making a request through an NSURLConnection.

You might be interested in checking out [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).  This library includes a category that adds a method to `UIImageView` that makes asynchronously loading an image from a remote URL as simple as this:

```
[self.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```